# AWS AppSync - Create Mutation returns Null

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I've got a simple AppSync API that has a type for City and Venue, the example is to map small retail shops. I'm trying to create a new City via the "Queries" pane within AppSync, I'm also wanting to provide a shortened ID - as opposed to the long autoId so that I can run queries for the shortened ID and the frontend app can use it from the params in the URL.

I'm trying to create a new item in DynamoDB with the following code:

Schema

```
type City {
  id: String!
  name: String!
}

type Mutation {
  ...
  createCity(input: CreateCityInput!): City
  ...
}

input CreateCityInput {
  id: String!
  name: String!
}
```

Mutation.createCity

```
// Request mapping template

{
  "version" : "2017-02-28",
  "operation" : "PutItem",
  "key" : {
    ## If object "id" should come from GraphQL arguments, change to $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.id)
    "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.id)
  },
  "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args)
}

// Response mapping template
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

Here's the mutation that I ran within the Queries page

```
mutation CreateCity {
  createCity(input: {
    id: "11538062"
    name: "Manchester"
  }) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

And this is the error that is returned from AppSync and or Dynamo

```
{
  "data": {
    "createCity": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createCity"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 32,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key id expected: S actual: NULL (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 7PU4D2...)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I can't see why I'm unable to perform a simple Create using a provided String as the ID and it identifies it as NULL...

Answer (score 0):

```
## Request Mapping

{
  "version" : "2017-02-28",
  "operation" : "PutItem",
  "key" : {
    "id" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.id)
  },
  "attributeValues" : {
    "name" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KoingDev - I changed the attributeValues to become
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input)